# In Lua, how do I remove a table within a table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

For example:

```
items = {
    [753] = {
    },
    [192] = {
    },
    [789] = {
    },
    [791] = {
    },
    [790] = {
    },
    [776] = {
    },
}
```

I would like to remove 789 and all data inside of it.  I tried both:
table.remove( items, 2 ); and table.remove( items, 789 ); ( I wasn't sure how the indexing worked ) with no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's as easy as

```
items[789] = nil
```

In Lua, if a key in a table has a `nil` value, then it's as though the key does not exist.

```
> t = { [5] = {}, [10] = {} }
> for k,v in pairs(t) do print(k,v) end
5       table: 0037CBC0
10      table: 0037CBE8
> t[5] = nil
> for k,v in pairs(t) do print(k,v) end
10      table: 0037CBE8
```

See also [Progamming in Lua, section 2.5](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html).  (Even though the online version is written for Lua 5.0, this still applies to Lua 5.1)

> ... you can assign nil to a table field to delete it.

When you assign `nil` to your index, that doesn't *explicitly* delete what was previously stored in that index; but it does lower the reference count for what was stored there, potentially making it eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help, been trying to do that a dozen different ways without luck :)

Comment: If you haven't used a garbage-collected language that uses reassignment to delete variables before, I don't think that assigning `nil` would be anyone's first guess.  Anyway, you're welcome.